# How can I programmatically create an iCal event in the default calendar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, calendar

How can I use Objective-C to programmatically create an iCal event in the default calendar? I want to check whether the event already exists and set the button state accordingly.

Comment: Its not a question.  Its a nice snippet for people like me who are looking for a solid example.

Comment: Can you edit the question *to make it a question* and then add the snippet as an answer? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Comment: please show the raw contents of PV_URL in a comment block

Answer (score 14):

An example of how to programmatically create an iCAL event in the default calendar, using Objective-C. The code checks if the event already exists, and sets the button state accordingly. Here is the code by @[codeburger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271034/codeburger):

```
-(void)initCalendar {

 // An array of 1 dictionary object, containing START and END values.
 NSMutableArray* pvDict  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:PV_URL ]];

 // Check if the private view event already exists in the default calendar.
 // Then set the calendar button state.

 // Get a entry point to the Calendar database.
 self.store = [[EKEventStore alloc ] init ];

 // Get an array of all the calendars.
 NSArray *calendars = store.calendars;

 // Get the default calendar, set by the user in preferences.
 EKCalendar *defaultCal = store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;

 // Find out if this calendar is modifiable.
  BOOL isDefaultCalModifiable = defaultCal.allowsContentModifications ;

 // Create an event in the default calendar.

  self.event = [ EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store ];

 self.event.title = CHELSEA_SPACE ;
 self.event.location = CHELSEA_ADDRESS ;

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];

 NSString *startString = [[ pvDict objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"starts" ];
 NSDate *dateStart = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startString];

 NSString *endString = [[ pvDict objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"ends" ];
 NSDate *dateEnd = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endString];

    self.event.startDate = dateStart;
 self.event.endDate   = dateEnd; 

 self.event.calendar = defaultCal ;

 // Alternative code to add 2.5 hours to start time.
 // [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:9000 sinceDate:event.startDate];

 // Search for events which match this date/time start and end.
 // Compare the matched events by event TITLE.

 NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:event.startDate 
           endDate:event.endDate calendars:calendars];

 NSArray *matchingEvents = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

 self.calendarButton.enabled = NO;

 if( ! isDefaultCalModifiable ) {
  // The default calendar is not modifiable
  return ;
 } 

 if ( [ matchingEvents count ] > 0 ) {

  // There are already event(s) which match this date/time start and end.
   // Check if this event is the PV

  EKEvent *anEvent;  
  int j;

  for ( j=0; j < [ matchingEvents count]; j++) {

   anEvent = [ matchingEvents objectAtIndex:j ] ;
   if([ CHELSEA_SPACE isEqualToString: anEvent.title ]) {
    // PV event already exists in calendar.
    return;
   }
  }
  [ anEvent release ];
 }

 self.calendarButton.enabled = YES;

 [ pvDict release ];
}

-(void)addEventToCalendar:(id)sender {

 NSError *error;
 BOOL saved = [self.store saveEvent:self.event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error]; 

 NSLog(@"Saved calendar event = %@\n", (saved ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
 self.calendarButton.enabled = NO;

}
```

I've seen this question with no answer and felt like it should be edited giving full credit to @[codeburger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271034/codeburger).

Answer (score 9):

```
 EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

 EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
 NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc ]init];//today,s date
 event.title = @"remainder";//title for your remainder

 event.startDate=date;//start time of your remainder
 event.endDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:1800 sinceDate:event.startDate];//end time of your remainder

 NSTimeInterval interval = (60 *60)* -3 ;
 EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:interval]; //Create object of alarm

 [event addAlarm:alarm]; //Add alarm to your event

 [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
  NSError *err;
  NSString *ical_event_id;
  //save your event
 if([eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err]){
        ical_event_id = event.eventIdentifier;
        NSLog(@"%@",ical_event_id);
 }

 for more info check this link
```

[sample for EKEvent](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160)