# How to check custom event added in the iPhone Calendar using iphone simulator

Tags: iphone

I have founded the code, Programmatically added custom event in the iPhone Calendar,using event kit framework.

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = @"EVENT TITLE";

event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];

[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

I used the above code and i want to check whether these event is added in iphone calendar or not.I have latest sdk 4.0 version, but my device is first generation of ipod device.so i can't launch my application in ipod (due to eventkit framework not supported).Is this possible to check this in iphone simulator ? Or anyother thoughts to check this custom event added in icalendar ?

Please help me . Thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 0):

Arrange a device to test it, else have faith in the developer documentation and simply follow the code sample given there and you should sail smoothly. :)

Answer (score 0):

[How can I programmatically create an iCal event in the default calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423486/programmatically-create-ical-event-and-test-for-event-existence)

This question covers how to add an event and then check for existence.

But yes, you will need to test on a device that is running a version of the OS that supports EventKit.  Otherwise you cannot ensure the on-device behavior of your app.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no calendar app in the simulator the entries are stored in a sqlite database in $HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator//Library/Calendar/Calendar.sqlitedb

Calendar Events are stored in several tables but mainly in a table called CalendarItem which can be opened with a sqlite viewer.

If you need a very easy sql lite viewer the FireFox plugin SQLite Manager works like a champ.

Hope this helps.
Rich